# AngularJS - Multiple StateParems

Tags: json, angularjs, api

We are still picking up and learning [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) but can't seem to figure this issue out, we want to be able to select a product type and use the formData value ("productType":"1") *image1* to display the correct JSON product data related to this ID *image2*.

These are our controllers *below* within app.js, we have tried using multiple $stateParems but cant get seem to get the producttype id working with the stateParems.

Each productType ID is related to its own JSONstub, this is what we are using currently but this only grabs the jobID and not the producttype id *below*.

```
$scope.productid = $stateParams.jobID[0];    
url: 'http://jsonstub.com/producttype/' + $scope.productid,
```

Here is our [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xBcWmbEQNKMHYqW7RtQM?p=preview), to find the Product Type section Click 'Login' > 'CHD24 - 26384108' 'View' > Next.

If anyone could advice and point us in the right direction this would help massively, also as we are new to [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) if you see anything else that we are doing wrongly please point it out.

Thank you.

```
// Product Type
.controller('warrantyCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
  $scope.params = $stateParams.jobID[0];
  $scope.dataLoaded = false;
  $http({
    url: 'http://jsonstub.com/warranty/' + $scope.params,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: '',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://run.plnkr.co',
      'JsonStub-User-Key': '1357f082-ea56-46f0-adc5-3e5c273f6f87',
      'JsonStub-Project-Key': 'e4f971a2-db30-45a0-80f9-bfa41b922c64'
    }
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.warrantydata = data;
    $scope.dataLoaded = true;
  }).error(function(data, status, error, config) {
    $scope.warrantydata = [{
      heading: "Error",
      description: "Could not load json data"
    }];
    $scope.dataLoaded = false;
  });
  $scope.formData = {
    'jobID': $scope.params
  };

  // Product Type Select
  $scope.products = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Petrol Lawnmower'
  }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Electric Lawnmower'
  }, {
    id: '3',
    name: 'Petrol Chainsaw'
  }, {
    id: '4',
    name: 'Electric Chainsaw'
  }, {
    id: '5',
    name: 'Petrol Timmer'
  }, {
    id: '6',
    name: 'Electric Timmer'
  }, {
    id: '7',
    name: 'Etc'
  }];
})


// Product Data
.controller('warrantyFormProductType', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
  $scope.productid = $stateParams.jobID[0];
  $http({
    url: 'http://jsonstub.com/producttype/' + $scope.productid, // This needs to be productType id
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: '',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://run.plnkr.co',
      'JsonStub-User-Key': '1357f082-ea56-46f0-adc5-3e5c273f6f87',
      'JsonStub-Project-Key': 'e4f971a2-db30-45a0-80f9-bfa41b922c64'
    }
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.productdata = data;
  }).error(function(data, status, error, config) {
    $scope.productdata = [{
      heading: "Error",
      description: "Could not load json data"
    }];
  })

  // Add / Remove Columns (Still working on)
  $scope.removeRow = function(index) {
    $scope.productdata.splice(index, 1);
    if ($scope.productdata.length() === 0) {
      $scope.productdata = [];
    }
  };
  $scope.addRow = function() {
    var newrow = [];
    if ($scope.productdata.length === 0) {
      newrow = [{
        'en': ''
      }];
    } else {
      $scope.productdata[0].forEach(function(row) {
        newrow.push({
          'en': ''
        });
      });
    }
    $scope.productdata.push(newrow);
  };
});
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: In your code `$scope.productid = $stateParams.jobID[0];`, what is the content of `$stateParams.jobID` and how come it is an array? How many params have you defined initially?


You must have defined your state by default params, can you provide that snippet? Something like this :
`$stateProvider.state('your.state', {
        url:'/product_type/:product_id',` ??

Comment: We are using url: '^/warranty/form/producttype/:jobID' within our state but when using multiple like url: '^/warranty/form/:jobID/producttype/:productID' it stopped working.

If it makes it easier I do have a plnkr set-up - http://plnkr.co/edit/xBcWmbEQNKMHYqW7RtQM?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Is your API request supposed to be like this `http://jsonstub.com/2/1` ?

Assuming yes, I've updated the code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CXgnsMwo3SG9TyoLZ25x?p=preview)

But I am getting Error 400 for this request.
Take a look and comment if this is what you needed.